# Writing a simple misc char device driver with read and write operations

Tags: kernel, drivers, devices

thank you for taking a look at this question.

I am writing a simple misc char device with read and write operations. Please keep reading ...

The following code prints the required text in `TEXT` only once when i do

```
cat /dev/mydevice01
```

This is the code to the read function.

```
static ssize_t my_read(struct file *file, char __user *buff, size_t count, loff_t *ppos)
{
    char *print_str = TEXT;

    if (*ppos != 0)
        return 0;
    if ((count < TEXT_LENGTH) || (copy_to_user(buff, print_str, TLF_ID_LENGTH)))
        return -EINVAL;
    *ppos += count;
    return count;
}
```

`TEXT` is defined using `#define` and so is `TEXT_LENGTH`

I felt this code was a little too complicated and hence, I tried to modify it. This is the modified code, but **that keeps printing the required text until I use a `SIGINT`** (<kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>) on the process:

```
static ssize_t my_read(struct file *file, char __user *buff, size_t count, loff_t *ppos)
{
        char *print_str = TLF_ID;

        if (copy_to_user(buff, print_str, TLF_ID_LENGTH))
                return -EINVAL;
        return count;
}
```

I am new to Linux kernel programming. I want to know what is going wrong with the code. And if possible, a single line of code that can implement the same functionality.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is it you cannot do, what is holding you back?

Comment: No, what I meant is I wanted to know why the modified code is printing the text repitatively. I basically want to simplify the code without affecting the result.

Comment: Is there a way to rewrite that function in a way that the whole function body is a single line of code? Other code in this program is just standard ```module_init(my_init)``` which in turn calls ```misc_register()``` for a ```struct miscdevice``` which has an ```fops .read``` attribute which ends up in this function.

Comment: Returning "count" means that "cat" never gets a read returning zero, so cat loops to read some more. You should see where *ppos is, and use that to see if it is greater than TEXT_LEN, and if so return 0. The original code is better than your modified code (at least it doesn't repeat indefinitely) but both are pretty bad.

Comment: And of course you need to update *ppos, the correct thing to do is to update it to the number of bytes written.

Comment: That means I will have to return bytes written and a case when *ppos != 0 to return 0, am I right?

Comment: Typically you want work out n=min(count, len -*ppos), if this is negative return 0.  otherwise copy n bytes from print_str+*ppos to buff, add n to *ppos and return n. This is better than the original code in that it allows you to read a byte at a time rather than insisting that you read the whole string at once.

Comment: Well one of the specifications is that the whole string is to be read at once, nothing less.

Comment: I am not able to guess what specifications you have, you have to list them. If that is the case then you need to check that *ppos = 0, and count >= TEXT_LEN to be sure that you are reading from the start and that you have enough to read the whole thing. You then set *ppos to TEXT_LEN and return TEXT_LEN after you have done the copy.

Comment: Yes, that should work, but that didn't really simply the code now, did it? The specifications are "Create a simple misc char device driver with read and write operations. When read from, it puts some text TEXT to the userspace all at once, nothing less than the full string." That means when I do ```cat /dev/mydevice01``` assuming the TEXT is ```sample_text``` , ```sample_text``` must be printed onto ```stdout``` . What I'm trying to ask is a simpler way than the first piece of code given above. Maybe something in a single line of code?

Comment: Please edit the question to add this additional information. Are you asking for existing helper functions in the kernel to handle some of the work? Something has to do the checks I listed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out myself, I'll leave the answer here to anyone else looking for something similar.

```
static ssize_t my_read(struct file *file, char __user *buff, size_t count, loff_t *ppos)
{
        char *print_str = TEXT;
        int len = TEXT_LENGTH;

        return simple_read_from_buffer(buff, count, ppos, print_str, len);
}
```

This works as it is supposed to. Just don't forget to include these modules.

```
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/miscdevice.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
```

Thank you all for the help :).

Comment: `simple_read_from_buffer` doesn't do what you said in the comments you required it to do, in particular it allows partial reads so you can read from part way through the string and don't have to read all the string.

Comment: I might not have noticed that, but this seemed like a valid solution for a single line code to help me obtain ```TEXT``` when I say ```cat /dev/mydevice01```. Thank you for the help Icarus :) Much appreciated.

Comment: `dd bs=1 seek=2 count=3 if=/dev/mydevice01` according to your specification should give an I/O error of some kind.

Comment: No, it did not. Do you mind telling me why you expected an I/O error of some sort? ```Fri Jun 19  07:29:21  bkkarthik <2003> ~/Workspace/mydevice01 $ dd bs=1 seek=2 count=3 if=/dev/mydevice01
jbsdkj
a243+0 records in
3+0 records out
```Please bear with me, I'm new to kernel programming.

Comment: The reason it should give an I/O error is because **you told us that it is specified to do so**! The original "complicated" code will do so, for example if you ask it to read less than the full length of the string. Usually people want what the `simple_read_from_buffer` provides, i.e. if you ask for only part of the string you get just part. You said that it had to produce "nothing less than the full string". so the only thing you can do if you are asked for part of the string is to return an error.

Comment: Right, my bad. Thank you for pointing it out for me.